# Look for specific word -- then change image

Tags: php, jquery

Let's say I have an image and a textfield. Whenever I type a specific word into the textfield... I want the image to dynamically and ajax-acally change (without reloading the web page) to the image I set it at...

How is this done? Maybe using PHP/jQuery?

Comment: I almost +1'd this for "ajax-acally." Awesome.

Comment: I thought that word was pretty cool.

Comment: It is fun to say, though most spell it "ajaxically".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with a server-side language like PHP.

Using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $('#textfield').change(function () {
     switch($(this).val()) {
       case 'some text':
         $('#image').attr('src', 'some image source');
         break;
       case 'some other text':
         $('#image').attr('src', 'some other source');
         break;
     }
   });
});
```

Alternatively, you could maintain a hash of text => image-src pairs.  Instead of a switch statement, you could simply see if the text the user has entered exists has a matching image src within the hash.

Comment: Only one thing... can I make it so it "fades" to anotehr image and instead of pressing enter It can be on Key press? :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution to start you off:

```
// bind to the keyup event of a text input
$("#textinput").keyup(function() {

    // when the event is triggered, send the captured text to the server
    // as the 'whichImage' param
    $.getJSON('image.php', { whichImage: $(this).val()}, function(json) {

        if(!json.error) {
            // modify the src (and whatever other attributes) to
            // whatever the response contains
            // another approach would be to send back an entire image tag and insert it
            // somewhere in the document
            $("#theImage").attr('src', json.src);
            $("#theImage").attr('width', json.width);
        } else {
            alert(json.error);
        } 
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['whichImage']) && !empty($_GET['whichImage'])) {

    // supposing that function returns array('src' => 'foo.jpg', 'width' => '250px') etc..
    $imgArray = getMatchingImage($_GET['whichImage']);
    if(!empty($imgArray)) {
        echo json_encode($imgArray);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'no match!'));
    }
    exit;
} 
?>
```

It would be a good idea to add a delay to sending captured text to the server, so requests are not constantly firing while the user is typing. Hope this was useful!

Comment: This looks promosing. But the image will NOT change in width so I can remove that. But how would I complete the PHP code because I think if I add the array inside the !empty check that it would not be right.